# Django Template Context Processor with Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a Login Class Based View which I want to include in all my pages. 
Is there a way to include Class Based View as template context processor, or do we have any other way to include in all pages ?

```
class LoginView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, FormView):
        form_class = LoginForm
        template_name = "account/login.html"
        success_url = None
        redirect_field_name = "next"

        def form_valid(self, form):
            success_url = self.get_success_url()
            return form.login(self.request, redirect_url=success_url)

        def get_success_url(self):
            # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
            ret = (get_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                         self.redirect_field_name)
                   or self.success_url)
            return ret

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            ret = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            signup_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                                       reverse("account_signup"),
                                                       self.redirect_field_name)
            redirect_field_value = self.request.REQUEST \
                .get(self.redirect_field_name)
            ret.update({"signup_url": signup_url,
                        "site": Site.objects.get_current(),
                        "redirect_field_name": self.redirect_field_name,
                        "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value})
            return ret

    login = LoginView.as_view()
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Views aren't context processors: they're, well, views. What exactly are you hoping to include on each page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [decorate the view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views):

Either in `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .views import VoteView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^about/', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="secret.html"))),
    (r'^vote/', permission_required('polls.can_vote')(VoteView.as_view())),
)
```

Or in `views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or, you can inherit from `LoginRequiredMixin` from [`django-braces`](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces):

```
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

class Index(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'sekret.html'
```

All these examples show how to require authentication for class based views (which I believe is what you are trying to do). The first two are directly from the documentation.

Once you implement either of the above examples, your application will behave like this:

1. A user enters a URL that maps to one of the above views.
2. django middleware checks if the user is logged in.
3. If not, django will redirect to [`LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#login-url), by default its `/accounts/login/`, and add a `?next` parameter, pointing to the original URL from #1.
4. The view from #3 will display a login form.
5. Once the user successfully authenticates, the view from #3 will update the session, and redirect the user to the URL from the `next` parameter.

If the user is logged in, then the decorated view will be executed as normal.